# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent tries to update non-existing column when nobody asked it to. (Many-to-Many relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship in a Laravel 5.6 app, using Eloquent ORM. I have `Customer` and `CustomerGroup` models, that correspond with the database tables of the same name, and a pivot table `customers_customergroups`. Relatively identical case is provided in Laravel's documentation with users and roles. The `customers_customergroups` table looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+
| customer_id | customergroup_id | created_at | updated_at |
+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+
|    53210    |        2         |     --     |     --     |
|    53210    |        4         |     --     |     --     |
|    53211    |        3         |     --     |     --     |
|    53211    |        4         |     --     |     --     |
+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+
```

My `Customer` model has a method called `customerGroups()` which retrieves all groups the customer belongs to.

```
public function customerGroups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\CustomerGroup', 'customers_customergroups', 'customer_id', 'customergroup_id');
}
```

The retrieval works fine, but when I try to update `Customer` by passing a `Request` object as an array to the `update()` Eloquent method, and in the same repository method I have to update the `customers_customergroups` table, the latter updates normally, but `Customer::find($id)->update($request->toArray())` throws an Exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'groups' in 'field list'....

There is no parameter named `groups` in the Request object passed to `Customer::find($id)->update();`

What happens here, why does this exception get thrown, what am I doing wrong, and how to do it properly?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit (posting the log requested in the comments below)**:

```
[2019-05-14 13:42:11] local.INFO: array (
  'id' => 53211,
  'name' => 'CUSTOMER ONE',
  'surname' => NULL,
  'Telephone' => '0123-4567890',
  'email' => 'email@example.com',
  'Street' => '22 BAKER STR.',
  'City' => 'LONDON',
  'Postal_code' => '1234',
  'is_active' => '1',
  'website' => '',
)
```

**Edit (Adding code requested by HCK):**

**Customer.js**

```
$scope.CreateCustomer = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid)
    {
        PostData    = {
          'id': $scope.customer_id,
          ... all other parameters from the previous edit ...
    }

    if(($scope.izbraniGrupi).length > 0)
    {
        PostData.izbraniGrupi = $scope.groupsSelected;
    }

    $http({
            method : 'PUT', // Laravel controller is a resource
            url : 'customers',
            data : PostData
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
           // Other stuff that happens on responseCode == 200.
        });
};
```

**CustomerController.php**

```
// $this->repository is defined normally in __construct() and works as supposed to.
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {
        $this->repository->update($id, $request);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message'  =>  $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' =>  'Customer updated'
    ]);
}
```

**CustomerRepository.php**

```
public function update($id, $data)
{
    if(isset($data['izbraniGrupi'])) {

        DB::table('customers_customergroups')->where(['customer_id' => $id])->delete();

        foreach ($data['izbraniGrupi'] as $group) {

            DB::table('customers_customergroups')->insert([
                'customer_id' => $id,
                'customergroup_id' => $group['id']
            ]);
        }

        unset($data['izbraniGrupi']);
    }

    Customer::find($id)->update($data->toArray());
}
```

Comment: Can you `Log::info($request->toArray());` and check in `/storage/logs/` to see what the request contains?

Comment: Could you add this right before the update and show us the generated SQL query with its bindings? e: helps if I include the code: `\DB::listen(function ($query) { dd($query->sql, $query->bindings); });`

Comment: Huh, that is odd. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Besides the query, could you also post a bit more context like the model and the controller?

Comment: @Dan It's strange that I dont see any INSERT INTO  or UPDATE query all it returns is a SELECT statement. 

    "select * from `customers` where (`id` = ?) limit 1"

And the bindings:
    array:1 [
      0 => "53211"
    ]

I updated the question, adding the missing `find($id)` method prior to `update()`. Could this be related?

Comment: @aynber This is the full error message I get: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'groups' in 'field list' (SQL: update `customers` set `updated_at` = 2019-05-14 14:01:02, `groups` = [{"id":3,"name":"Test Subjects","created_at":"2018-11-13 04:29:32","updated_at":"2018-11-13 04:29:32","pivot":{"customer_id":53211,"customergroup_id":3}},{"id":4,"name":"New Customer Group","created_at":"2019-05-10 13:04:17","updated_at":"2019-05-10 13:14:55","pivot":{"customer_id":53211,"customergroup_id":4}}] where `id` = 53211)

Comment: If the `UPDATE` query can't be executed, I guess that's normal it doesn't return it.

Comment: Yes, this is related. This snipped only shows the first query before it aborts. You basically send two queries in one line. If you split this up and place it between, it should show the correct sql.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I replaced the dd() with a simple dump() and the result posted is after the change. Yet, no UPDATE query.

Comment: Do you have a boot method in your customers model?

Comment: @aynber No, I don't. But how is that related?

Comment: A boot method could have an updating/updated trigger that might try to save additional data somewhere, which is why it was a thought.

Comment: @EmilAvramov please, provide the related code in your question: request payload and controller function.

Comment: @HCK I updated the question.

Comment: @EmilAvramov try my response, in case this didn't work, could you paste the `dd($data)` right before the last sentence of your `update()` method in your Repository class?

Comment: @HCK The data is the same as the first edit of my question (the log).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is related to the use of the full Request class instead of just getting the payload. Try this:

**CustomerController.php**

```
...
$this->repository->update($id, $request->all());
// or even better:                    ^^^^^^^^
$this->repository->update($id, $request->only('the', 'fields', 'that', 'you', 'expect'));
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Not related but I noticed that you are doing this inside your repository:

```
...      
DB::table('customers_customergroups')->where(['customer_id' => $id])->delete();

foreach ($data['izbraniGrupi'] as $group) {

    DB::table('customers_customergroups')->insert([
        'customer_id' => $id,
        'customergroup_id' => $group['id']
    ]);
}
...
```

This looks to me that you are detaching all the related records in order to re-attach the *customer groups* to *customers*. This looks a good case for [Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
Customer::find($id)->customerGroups()->sync(collect($data['izbraniGrupi'])->pluck('id'));
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But, if from the Controller I pass the whole Request object (without `->all()`) and then in the Repository, inside the `Customer::find($id)->update($data->toArray())`, I change it to `Customer::find($id)->update($data->except('group'))` which converts the $data object to array automatically, does it make sense? Because it throws the same exception.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Both methods should return a subset of the retrieved data. This is really weird because it is trying to save the relationship groups. Did you have it defined in your `Customer` object? Did you append the relationship in the model?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you! Do I have defined what in my `Customer` object? The additional `groups` parameter? No. Also, the relationship is defined in a customerGroups() method in my model (second code block in my question) and for retrieval it works fine.

Comment: Yeah I've just seen it. I missed that. Really weird.

Comment: @EmilAvramov Did you solved your issue? If so, what was the problem? I'm intrigued.

Comment: Not yet, it's put on hold for now. I will definitely write the solution here :)